# Use .NET core rc 2 on windows virtual server hosting

Tags: .net, server, windows-server, .net-core

I googled for this question, but unfortunately I did't found anything related to this topic.

I know I can use Azure, but this is for a little homepage way to expensive! (I know the Free mode, but this is just for dev phase an option)

So, I would rent a Windows virtual server (vServer) to host, but I want to work with .NET core RC2 on that new page.

The question is, can I use this on vServers (Did anyone already do that?) because on vServers you dont have ALL rights that you have on dedicted servers.

But I don't want to rent a server and than recognize that it don't work.

Kind regards

Comment: Due to the dependencies, it is very likely that you have to call the support team of your virtual server provider.

Comment: If you target `platform` the dependencies should be included when publishing the app. That means that no extra packages need to be installed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you target `.NET Core RC2 (netcoreapp1.0)` you can run your app on any system, including a Linux VM.

**For Windows:**

If you want to use Windows (which requires license costs) all you need is the newest ISS Webserver Installation and admin rights to install packages via the Web Platform installer.

See the ASP.net documentation for more information on how to publish to ISS: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html

**For Linux:**

You however need some sort of access to edit the webserver config and install a monitoring package for managing the Kestrel server.

See the .NET Core documentation for details: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/linuxproduction.html

> Prerequisites
>
> - Access to an Ubuntu 14.04 Server with a standard user account with sudo privilege.
> - An existing ASP.NET Core application.